# PHP soapClient returns empty arrays for empty tags

Tags: php, soap

I'm using PHP's soapClient class to get results from my JBoss server.

But where the SOAP XML response includes empty tags, my PHP code includes empty arrays:

The SOAP response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:someSoap xmlns:ns2="someUrl" xmlns:ns3="someUrl">
         <ns2:method>
            <ns3:tag1/>
            <ns3:tag2>value</ns3:tag2>
          </ns2:method>
       </ns2:someSoap>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The PHP array I'm getting back:

```
array(1) {
  ["method"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["tag1"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["tag2"]=>
      string(9) "value"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What were you expecting? And how are you configuring the SoapClient?

Comment: I guess I'm expecting an empty string... Not sure how to answer the second question. What configuration options do I have?

Comment: The wsdl includes type="xs:string" for this variable

Comment: When creating your SoapClient instance, you can give an options array. About the expectations: It really depends, NULL would be another expectable value, but all this depends on both the WSDL and the SoapClient configuration.

Comment: Thanks Sven. When I initiate the soapClient class I direct it to the wsdl file with all the type settings (which is a string in the above example), but it doesn't seem to help at all. I understand from your reply that I should pass the class typemap settings, but can find no documentation for it. Can you please help further?

Comment: There is no code in your question that shows how you instantiate the SoapClient. What are you thinking you should do? I haven't suggested anything, I still have no clue.